# How to use End(xlUp) to clear all rows starting from cell A4

Tags: excel, vba

The below code clear all cells on column `A` starting from cell `A4`.
Please, How to adapt this code to clear all rows starting from cell `A4`.

```
Range("A4", ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.count).End(xlUp)).Clear
```

Comment: Insert `.EntireRow` before the `.Clear`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is given by @GSerg in the comment above.

Here is another way (**Shorter code**)

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet '<~~ OR Change this to the relevant sheet

ws.Rows("4:" & ws.Rows.Count).Clear
```